# How to customize a FB Login Button in swift 2?

Tags: swift, facebook

Im new to swift and Im trying to customize a facebook login button. I was able to create a default button using FBSDKLoginButton (without creating a UIButton in storyboard) in the class of the view controller `class LoginViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButton`.
   When I add a button in storyboard and create a outlet in the view controller, XCode indicates this error: "Multiple inheritance from classes `UIViewController` and `FBSDKLoginButton`"
   This is what I tried but the code crashes as soon as I click the UIButton that I created in the storyboard:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var fbButton: UIButton!

var idU = ""
var nomeU = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    fbButton.frame = CGRectMake(160, 100, 50, 50)
    fbButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * fbButton.bounds.size.width
    fbButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"fb"), forState: .Normal)
    fbButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("fbLoginInitiate"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(fbButton)


    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil)
    {
        print("Not logged in")
    }
    else
    {
        print("This is where you perform a segue.")

        performSegueWithIdentifier("next", sender: self)
    }

}


@IBAction func fbLoginInitiate(sender: AnyObject) {

    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id,email,name,picture.width(480).height(480)"])
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in


        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {   // pega nome e email do usuário:
            print("fetched user: \(result)")
            let userName : NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString
            print("User Name is: \(userName)")
            let userEmail : NSString = result.valueForKey("email") as! NSString
            print("User Email is: \(userEmail)")

            // pega a imagem do usuário:

            if let data = result["picture"]?!["data"]
            {
                if let url = data!["url"] as? String
                {
                    let profilePictureURL = url
                    let imgURL = NSURL(string: profilePictureURL)
                    let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL!)
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("next", sender: self)

                }
            }

            self.idU = result.valueForKey("id") as! String
            self.nomeU = userName as String
            print("LOGIIIIN NOMEEE: \(self.nomeU)")
            print("LOGIIIIN ID: \(self.idU)")
        }
    })
}
```

Does anyone know how can I customize a Facebook login button? I know it's possible, but I don't know what to try anymore! Any help it's very appreciated!

NOTE: All of the `graphRequest` body was working perfectly before adding the UIButton in storyboard!